# How to convert date in format 09-feb-73 to 02/09/1973 (mm/dd/yyyy) using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

How to convert date in format 09-feb-73  to 02/09/1973 (mm/dd/yyyy) using Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Valid Ruby datetime formats](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html)

```
Date.strptime("09-feb-73", "%d-%b-%y").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Note that `strptime` is a part of Rails. And these are the relevant formats used:

> %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
>
> %d - Day of the month (01..31)
>
> %m - Month of the year (01..12)
>
> %y - Year without a century (00..99)
>
> %Y - Year with century

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`Date.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000358) and [`Date#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000447):

```
d = Date.parse('09-feb-73').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# "02/09/1973"
```

You could also use [`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000357) instead of `Date.parse`:

```
d = Date.strptime('09-feb-73', '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# "02/09/1973"
```

The advantage of `strptime` is that you can specify the format rather than leaving it to `parse` to guess.

Comment: The result I got was 02/09/0073

Answer (score 0):

Date.strptime("09-feb-73", "%d-%b-%y").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
Date Formats: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255

Answer (score 0):

If you require this in a view, I would suggest using localizations, since you can easily change the behavior based on your user's local settings and keep your controller code tidy (why should the controller care about the date format?). Example:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "%m/%d/%Y"


# view file
<%=l Time.now, :format => :short %>
```

For more information on rails localizations, see the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).